# Calculate due dates inside query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table consisting of Billed Date & Payment Terms like this. The `TODAY` cell is just a reference:

[image]

I need to use a query to select & identify which one is overdue for over 30 days. I know a solution is to create another column that calculates the Due Date from the Net and selects one that are later than 30 days compared to `Today()` with this formula:

```
=QUERY(A2:B3,"SELECT A, B WHERE A <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the Due Date inside the query without having to create a new column for it. Something like

```
"SELECT A WHERE A + RIGHT(B:B,2) - 30 > 30
```

Thank you!

Comment: Then it would return empty result for given two date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like-

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula((A2:A4+INDEX(SPLIT(B2:B4," "),,2))),"where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! I didn't know we can use ArrayFormula for it. One last question. Some Payment Terms is "Due upon Receipt", can we use ```IF ( )``` so when that happens, we will use the Bill Date as the Due Date too? Again. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try like `INDEX(SPLIT(IF(B2:B5="Due upon Receipt",0,B2:B5)," "),,2)`. If the answer helps then please accept (tick mark it).

Comment: Thanks! Also, It seems like the formula only retrieves data from Col1. What could I do to make it also retrieves Col2 as well? Like this table: https://ibb.co/vhvFZXg Thanks!

Comment: Then try `=QUERY({ArrayFormula((A2:A5+INDEX(SPLIT(IF(C2:C5="Due upon Receipt",0,C2:C5)," "),,2))),B2:B5},"select Col1, Col2 where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ticked the mark and upvoted all your answers!

Comment: @RexNguyen Glad to know! That's the way to say thanks in stackoverflow.